# Spring JmsTemplate release resource (IBM model queue)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jms, ibm-mq

I am currently implementing a SpringBoot application that writes to dynamically created IBM queues (model queues). After writing, these queues are no longer released, so that the coupling facility is full of queues and no new model queues can be created.

In my SpringBoot application I use the JMSTemplate to write TextMessages to the model queues (destination).

What do I have to do, that the resource is released and the queues can be closed by the QueueManager, if they are not used anymore?

The following is the implementation of the Producer.

```java
@Service
public class MessageSender {

    private final JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    public MessageSender(JmsTemplate jmsTemplate) {
        this.jmsTemplate = jmsTemplate;
    }

    /**
     * Verschickt eine Bytesmessage an die angegebene Destination
     *
     * @param destination Zieladresse
     * @param text        Inhalt der Nachricht
     */
    public void sendMessage(Destination destination, String text) {
        try {
            jmsTemplate.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);
            jmsTemplate.setDefaultDestination(destination);
            jmsTemplate.send(destination, session -> {
                TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage(text);
                message.setJMSDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);
                return message;
            });
            jmsTemplate.
        } catch (InvalidDestinationException e) {
            StatisticLogger.logMessageSenderError(destination, text);
        }
    }
    
}

@Configuration
@EnableJms
public class JmsConfiguration {

    /**
     * Erstellt ein neues JMS-Template
     * @param connectionFactory Connection-Factory
     * @return JMS-Template
     */
    @Bean
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate();
        
        jmsTemplate.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        jmsTemplate.setExplicitQosEnabled(true);
        // Der Delivery-Mode muss NON_PERSISTANT sein, da die dynamische Rueckantwort-Queue keine persistenten 
        // Nachrichten verarbeiten kann!
        jmsTemplate.setDeliveryPersistent(false);
        
        return jmsTemplate;
    }
    
}

@JmsListener(destination = "${ibm.mq.queue}")
public void receiveMessage(Message message) {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Destination destination = null;
    try {
        destination = message.getJMSReplyTo();
        if (destination == null) {
            LOGGER.error(ERROR_MARKER, "Keine ReplyTo-Destination gegeben.");
            return;
        }
        byte[] bytes = getBytesFromByteMessage(message);
        Daten daten = processor.generateDatenFromBytes(bytes);
        messageSender.sendMessage(destination, buildRzDatenMessage(daten));

    } catch (JMSException e) {
        ...
    }
}
```

I hope you could help me.

Answer (score 0):

Check your model queue definition. Since TDQs cannot be shared queues (using the coupling facility), you must be using a Permanent Dynamic Queue which will live beyond being closed.

Comment: Hi Mark, 
i am the admin of the qmgr's Patrick is working with.
We have administrative jobs in our environment to delete those queues but they are still in use (OPPROC>0) by his application.

Comment: And you are right, the queue is Shared Dynamic :   
DEFINE QMODEL('LOHNID.SIGNATUR.MODEL') QSGDISP(GROUP) DEFTYPE(SHAREDYN)        CFSTRUCT('QUEUET') USAGE(NORMAL) INDXTYPE(NONE) STGCLASS('LOHNID') MAXDEPTH(5000)  MAXMSGL(200) DEFPRTY(0) DEFPSIST(NO) DEFPRESP(SYNC) MSGDLVSQ(PRIORITY) SHARE DEFSOPT(SHARED) NOTRIGGER